# Imprimir instantáneamente (con una impresora de agujas) atributos seleccionados de un objeto en Angular CLI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, impresión, angular-cli, impresora

En mi aplicación web necesito que al clickar en la fila de una tabla imprima la fecha de la tabla y su id en la cabecera de un folio mediante una impresora de agujas. Sin comprobaciones, sin el asistente de impresión que tienen los navegadores (osea, que imprima directamente).

Uso ASP.netCore para el servidor y AngularCLI para el cliente. He buscado varias opciones pero las más viables están en php y no me sirven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré la respuesta aquí

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/64b36166-2e7c-4c93-a031-046a5db1111c/imprimir-desde-c?forum=vcses

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/5d5ed216-4b65-471c-993a-cbc65ec10984/imprimir-por-la-impresora-c-aspnet?forum=netfxwebes